# Coldfusion Dynamic Variable (?) parsed to SQL Query

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

This is the first time I am attempting to parse a variable to a CF query, but I have run into a few little issues.

In summary, I am creating a pivot table of sales by operators by week. Manually, no hassle, but I only want a subset of weeks, not all. Again, no real problem if I want hardcoded weeks, but the problem comes in when I try and parse a week number to the SQL query to create the subset of dynamic weeks.

The CFDUMP shows me that the query is executing based on what I am sending to it, **but when it comes to outputting the value of the field (the week), it takes the variable name value, and not the field value if that makes sense?**

I know that I shouldn't be having field names as values, but I still tryingh to test right now. With the manual query, I prefix the week number with a 'W' e.g. W9, but when I try and do that I get

**MANUAL QUERY**

```
SELECT UserName,
       ISNULL([W6], 0) AS [W6],
       ISNULL([W7], 0) AS [W7],
       ISNULL([W8], 0) AS [W8],
       ISNULL([W9], 0) AS [W9],
       ISNULL([W10], 0) AS [W10]
  FROM (   SELECT CASE
                       WHEN SUBSTRING(Username, 1, 3) = 'd.S' THEN 'DS'
                       WHEN SUBSTRING(Username, 1, 3) = 'p.R' THEN 'PR'
                       WHEN SUBSTRING(Username, 1, 3) = 'j.G' THEN 'JG'
                       WHEN SUBSTRING(Username, 1, 3) = 'b.c' THEN 'BC'
                       ELSE 'Other' END AS Username,
                  CONCAT('W', DATEPART(isowk, ERCFullAuditDate)) as XWeek,
                  COUNT(1) [SalesCount]
             FROM [ERC-Transactions].[dbo].[ERC-Audit]
            WHERE (   ERCModule = 'Carriage Return on Account'
                AND   ERCFullAuditDate >= DATEADD(week, -4, GETDATE())
                 OR   (   ERCFullAuditDate <= DATEADD(week, -52, convert(datetime, GETDATE()))
                    and   ERCFullAuditDate >= DATEADD(week, -56, convert(datetime, GETDATE()))))
            GROUP BY DATEPART(isowk, ERCFullAuditDate),
                     UserName) ST
  PIVOT (   SUM(SalesCount)
            for XWeek in ([W6], [W7], [W8], [W9], [W10])) as StorePivot
```

The above yields this result.

[image]

**THE COLDFUSION DYNAMIC QUERY**

Now when I try and do the same, but by parsing variables to the query, the CFDUMP yields the correct values, but as I said, when I try and output this, I get the field name and not the value.

To be honest, I have two issues here in that I need to address. The variable field name, but also when I come to adding the concatenation of 'W' to the week number, I am seeing an 'Error converting data type nvarchar to int.' I think I may need a ***cfqueryparam***, but I am not sure.

```
<cfset WEEK_2 = DATETImeFormat(DateAdd("ww",-2,now()),"w")>
           
<cfoutput>Week: #WEEK_2#</cfoutput> (This is the value of the WEEK_2 variable)<br>       

<cfset XX = "">
<cfset XX = XX & "SELECT UserName, ">
<cfset XX = XX & "ISNULL([#WEEK_2#], 0) AS [#WEEK_2#] ">
<cfset XX = XX & "FROM (   SELECT CASE ">
<cfset XX = XX & "WHEN SUBSTRING(Username,1,3) = 'd.S' THEN 'DS' ">
<cfset XX = XX & "WHEN SUBSTRING(Username,1,3) = 'p.R' THEN 'PR' ">
<cfset XX = XX & "WHEN SUBSTRING(Username,1,3) = 'j.G' THEN 'JG' ">
<cfset XX = XX & "WHEN SUBSTRING(Username,1,3) = 'b.c' THEN 'BC' ">
<cfset XX = XX & "ELSE 'Other' END AS Username, ">
<cfset XX = XX & "DATEPART(isowk, ERCFullAuditDate) as XWeek, ">
<cfset XX = XX & "COUNT(1) [SalesCount] ">
<cfset XX = XX & "FROM [EBS-ERC-Transactions].[dbo].[ERC-Audit] ">
<cfset XX = XX & "WHERE (   ERCModule = 'Carriage Return on Account' ">
<cfset XX = XX & "AND   ERCFullAuditDate >= DATEADD(week, -4, GETDATE()) ">
<cfset XX = XX & "OR   (   ERCFullAuditDate <= DATEADD(week, -52, convert(datetime, GETDATE())) ">
<cfset XX = XX & "and   ERCFullAuditDate >= DATEADD(week, -56, convert(datetime, GETDATE())))) ">
<cfset XX = XX & "GROUP BY DATEPART(isowk, ERCFullAuditDate), ">
<cfset XX = XX & "UserName) ST ">
<cfset XX = XX & "PIVOT (   SUM(SalesCount) ">
<cfset XX = XX & "for XWeek in ([#WEEK_2#])) as StorePivot ">

<cfquery name = "QueryTest" dataSource = "EBSERC"> 
    #PreserveSingleQuotes(XX)# 
</cfquery>

<br>

<cfoutput Query="QueryTest">
    #UserName#, #WEEK_2#<br>
</cfoutput>

<br>
<cfdump var="#QueryTest#" />
```

And this is the result ...

[image]

Ultimately, as mentioned before, I want to concatenate 'W' to the week number field.

[image]

Any guidance or a steer in the right direction will be VERY appreciated and thanks for your time.

**Thank you very much for reading.**

Comment: Ignoring the question for a second ...  1) The `WHERE` clause isn't doing what you think.  It currently mixes AND/OR which may produce unexpected results. The current clause essentially does this  *where Col1 = X **AND** Col2 = Y **OR** Col2 = Z*   ... but should be grouping the conditions like this:  *where Col1 = X **AND** ( Col2 = Y **OR** Col2 = Z )* 2) There shouldn't be a need for all the concatenation.  Strings can usually span multiple lines, and there's always cfsavecontent if needed.  Removing all the "&" will greatly improve readability

Comment: Small code shortcut that you might like; for concat strings, you can use the &= operator: <cfset XX &= "next statement ">.

Comment: Hello Scott - thanks a ton for the feedback and tip. That will make a massive difference in the old way I do things. Cheers for that, Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long for comments.

Since the column labels are dynamic and closely bound to the database, I'd probably do this all on the database side. Preferably inside a stored procedure.

If you're using SQL Server 2017+, a CTE could be used to generate the weeks within the desired date range. Then [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) used to convert the results into comma separated lists.

> ```
> ; WITH dates AS (
>    -- Generate range between -56 and -52 weeks ago
>    SELECT DateAdd(wk, -56, GETDATE()) AS WeekDate
>    UNION ALL
>    SELECT DateAdd(wk, 1, WeekDate)
>    FROM   dates
>    WHERE  DateAdd(wk, 1, WeekDate) <= DateAdd(wk, -52, GETDATE())
> )
> , dateLabels AS (
>   -- extract week number and construct label "W1","W2",etc..
>   SELECT  DATEPART(isowk, WeekDate) AS WeekNum
>           , QUOTENAME( CONCAT('W', DATEPART(isowk, WeekDate) )) AS WeekLabel
>   FROM   dates
> )
> -- convert to comma separated lists
> SELECT STRING_AGG( WeekLabel, ',') 
>             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY WeekNum) AS PivotColumns
>       , STRING_AGG( CONCAT('ISNULL(', WeekLabel, ',0) AS ', WeekLabel ), ',') 
>             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY WeekNum) AS SelectColumns
> FROM  dateLabels
> ;
> ```

The results would look like this (minus any line wrapping)

> | PivotColumns | SelectColumns |
> | --- | --- |
> | [W6],[W7],[W8],[W9],[W10] | ISNULL([W6],0) AS [W6],ISNULL([W7],0) AS [W7],ISNULL([W8],0) AS [W8],ISNULL([W9],0) AS [W9],ISNULL([W10],0) AS [W10] |

Then simply plug the two lists into the SQL query. In CF:

```
<cfscript>
   // ...
   sqlString = "
        SELECT UserName 
               , #SelectColumns#
        FROM (   

                ... 

             ) ST
             PIVOT 
             (   
                SUM(SalesCount)
                FOR XWeek IN ( #PivotColumns# )

             ) AS StorePivot
    ";

    qPivot = queryExecute( sqlString );
    // ...
</cfscript>
```

**Results:**

> ```
> SELECT UserName
>       , ISNULL([W6],0) AS [W6]
>       , ISNULL([W7],0) AS [W7]
>       , ISNULL([W8],0) AS [W8]
>       , ISNULL([W9],0) AS [W9]
>       , ISNULL([W10],0) AS [W10]
> FROM (   
>
>       ... 
>       
>    ) ST
>    PIVOT (   
>           SUM(SalesCount)
>           FOR XWeek IN ( 
>               [W6],[W7],[W8],[W9],[W10]
>           )
>   ) AS StorePivot
> ```

---

**`WHERE` oh where are the parentheses?**

A few observations about the original query:

The current `WHERE` clause is incorrect. When mixing AND/OR operators, parentheses must be used to ensure the order of operations. *Conceptually*, the current query is doing this:

> ```
>    WHERE Condition1 AND Condition2 OR Condition3
> ```

It should be using parentheses here:

> ```
>    WHERE Condition1 AND ( Condition2 OR Condition3 )
> ```

[GETDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) already returns a `datetime` value, so there's no need to convert it to a datetime again here:

> `DATEADD(week, -52, convert(datetime, GETDATE()))`

Lastly, there shouldn't be a need for all the concatenation. Strings can usually span multiple lines, and there's always cfsavecontent if needed. Removing all the `&` will greatly improve readability.

Comment: SOS, as always, thank you! I see where you are coming from and it all makes sense. I just need to spend some time now and get familiar with stored procedures and injecting it into the script. I will come back to you on the outcome.

Comment: You're welcome. Technically, you could use two cfquery's, like in the above code, instead of a procedure as well. A procedure makes more sense, IMO, but either works.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to copy the SQL exactly I think you missed the 'W' in the cfset at the top:

<cfset WEEK_2 = 'W' & DATETImeFormat(DateAdd("ww",-2,now()),"w")>

Outputs:

Week: W9 (This is the value of the WEEK_2 variable)

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. I think I did try that at one point, but got a 'Error converting data type nvarchar to int.' I get the error message, just not sure if the w9 is meant to be parsed as a date possible (with out the 'w') if that makes sense.

Comment: @MrJackson - It should work fine as long as you add a leading "W" to the "XWeek" column as well: `CONCAT('W', DATEPART(isowk, ERCFullAuditDate)) as XWeek,`.  If you forgot to add it, that may be the problem you encountered.

Answer (score 2):

You have this command:

```
<cfset XX = XX & "ISNULL([#WEEK_2#], 0) AS [#WEEK_2#] ">
```

Since the week_2 variable has a value of 9, when that command gets executed, it becomes this:

```
<cfset XX = XX & "ISNULL([9], 0) AS [9] ">
```

and your query becomes

```
select username
, 9 as 9
from etc
```

You are going to have to put some more thought into generating your week numbers.